# Each four character it value should be move to new line

Tags: javascript

```
var maxLength = 4;
    e = jQuery.Event("keypress")
    e.which = 13
    $('#input').on('input focus keydown keyup', function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm); 
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].length > maxLength) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, maxLength);
                //lines[i] = lines[i];
            }
        }
        $(this).val(lines.join(''));
    });
```

After each 4 number value should be gone to next line i apply this code does not work please guide

Comment: Use `join('\n')`at least...

Comment: Please share a working snippet.

Comment: A working snipped would be great, yes.

Comment: when i type 1 to 4 it should be in one line with 5-8 then new line then 9-12 so on..

Comment: @gurvinder372 updated fieddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that your input doesn't have any line-breaks before segregating them again by chunks

```
$('#mytext').on('input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().split( "\n" ).join( "" );   
  var output = getChunks( value, 4 );
  $(this).val(output.join("\n"));
});

function getChunks(str, chunk) {
  var i, j;
  var output = [];
  var array = str.split( "" );
  for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) 
  {
    output.push( array.slice(i, i + chunk).join( "" ) );
  }
  return output;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#mytext').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 )
  {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert( "Enter was pressed" );
     this.blur();
     return false;
  }
});


$('#mytext').on('input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().split( "\n" ).join( "" );   
  var output = getChunks( value, 4 );
  $(this).val(output.join("\n"));
});

function getChunks(str, chunk) {
  var i, j;
  var output = [];
  var array = str.split( "" );
  for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) 
  {
    output.push( array.slice(i, i + chunk).join( "" ) );
  }
  return output;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytext" name="text_body"></textarea>
```

Comment: i wont be able to enter from now even i want to hit enter

Comment: is this possible that count from new line ?

Comment: I know but it should allow to enter

Comment: @Ricky Didn't get you! Did you checked the demo?

Comment: Yes i mean when alert( "Enter was pressed" ); this should not come user should allow to press enter and have new line

Comment: If you allow enter, it will mess up with chunk division as while dividing into chunk a line-break is added as well.

Comment: I know is there any other way.. :(